# Where might one look to find a wonky keymapping?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I've got kind of a weird problem.

I was trying to take a screenshot today, using PrintScr as usual, but it wasn't working. I went hunting for why and found that PrintScr is issuing the keys Option-Shift-4. In a text editor, it types "$".

I know why it might be doing this. At some point I was trying to map Option-Shift-4 to take a screenshot, so that my Mac muscle memory wouldn't have to shift across computers. Foolish, I know.

I'm on Pop!_OS 22.04 with a 6.2 kernel and Gnome, mostly default setup for Pop.

The problem is, I cannot for the life of me find where this is configured.

I looked in /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/, everywhere an Xmodmap config might be set or loaded, Gnome Tweaks, various GUI tools... I can't find anything that might be doing this.

So two questions:

1: Where are all the places I should look?

2: How might one completely reset the keyboard configuration? This was the only change I made, and I have no other changes I want to keep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered my own issue here-- my keyboard (a Keychron K8) has a Windows/Mac switch on it, and in general is a very mac-centric keyboard.

When that switch is set to "Mac," the keyboard itself sends "Cmd+Shift+4" when PrtScr is pressed.

I just had to switch the dumb guy switch to "Windows" and then swap the Ctrl and Opt keys using Xmodmap, which is a more common operation.

---